# Can't load the package rcommander in MacOS Sonoma

Tags: r, package, macos-sonoma, factominer

When trying to load the package Rcmdr, even before, there is a message that says:

- "WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES."

I've tried evertything I could but it's impossible for me to solve it. Does anyone know what can I do?

I tried everything, my level is not to high but I managed other times...

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. 
This seems to be an issue related to MacOS Sonoma, at least from a quick internet search I can see other programs having the same warnings on MacOS. 
Can you load the package and is everything working fine? I mean, it is just a warning, not an error. So if everything is working, I would choose to ignore it, because very likely it is out of your hands to fix the program to not show a warning with your MacOS Sonoma. This is a thing for package authors. You can try filing an issue in the GitHub repository of the package, to make the authors aware of the problem.

Comment: Hi uke! I can't even load the package... I've tried everything I could but it's impossible to do it. I'm gonna try to write them and see if there's any solution. The problem is that I need Rcmdr because a Uni work...

Comment: In the meantime, you could use the free online RStudio in your webserver and see if the problem persists: https://posit.cloud is running R and Rstudio on a remote Linux server, so no MacOS Sonoma problems.

Comment: Hi again! I was trying to run Rcmdr in my windows laptop but this error comes:Loading required package: splines
Loading required package: RcmdrMisc
Loading required package: car
Loading required package: carData
Loading required package: sandwich
Loading required package: effects
lattice theme set by effectsTheme()
See ?effectsTheme for details.
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rcmdr’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk2', details:
  call: file.exists("~/.Rtk2theme")
  error: file name conversion problem -- name too long?

Comment: this seems to be out of scope for this question. the error you are describing (`file name conversion problem -- name too long?`) is common and there are many questions here on SO. Chances are, that this is somewhat unrelated to the problem on MacOS. If you do not find an answer, try posting a new question with your specific error on windows and link it here.